# Showing datepicker over Modalbox

Tags: javascript, datepicker, modal-dialog

Im trying to show a [datepicker](http://code.google.com/p/prototype-datepicker-widget/) inside a [Modalbox](http://github.com/okonet/modalbox). I tried almost everything. Changed the zindex to a higher number then the modalbox, also loaded the datepicker after showing the modalbox, but nothing.
Any known issue with this? Suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I was using the onUpdate callback of the modalbox. With "afterLoad", everything works